# iOS status bar cordova color

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova

after looking up all the questions and the directions I cannot seem to change my color of my banner I have tried `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent` and other solutions that are not helpful what so ever. This only an issue on iOS 7

in `viewdidload` and `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` this is what I have `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];`

Comment: What code are you currently using?

Comment: at that point only that

Comment: Where did you put `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent`?

Comment: `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, and have tried `viewdidload`

Comment: Then please post your `viewDidLoad` code along with your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` code.

Comment: same for both `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the background was set to default. 'self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];' fixed the issue